# Crashing Safari on iPhone 4/4s (iOS 7.0.1) when zooming in on text input field (and only when zooming)

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, safari, mobile-safari

Safari crashes consistently on an iPhone 4/4s running iOS 7 when zooming in on a text field on our site. Our site works fine on an iPhone 5 and on desktops.

To reproduce:

1) Visit [www.panabee.com](http://www.panabee.com) from an iPhone 4/4s.

2) Run a search with two terms (e.g., "stackoverflow rocks").

3) After the results page loads, zoom into the search field at the top. Adjust the search terms. Safari crashes. You must zoom. If you adjust the search terms without zooming, the site works fine.

The following jQuery code executes upon editing the text field:

```
function text_field_onclick( field ) {
    field = $( field );
    if ( field.hasClass('tip') ) {
        field.removeClass('tip');
        field.val( '' );
    }
}


function text_field_onblur( field ) {
    field = $( field );
    if ( !field.val() ) {
        field.addClass('tip');
        field.val( field.attr('tip') );
    }
}
```

Why is Safari crashing? Is it something with our site?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the crash logs to see if anything sticks out?

Comment: iOS 7.0 is notoriously crashy, especially on older devices. It's Apple's fault, not yours.

Comment: If you're sure, @AndrewMedico, post this as an answer, and we'll give you the bounty assuming no one disproves you.

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. no we haven't simply because we isolated the cause to the zoom behavior. what's the best way to view the crash logs on mobile safari?

Comment: @Crashalot I would use xcode. When you plug in the device, you should see "Organizer" start up. You may need to pair the device for Development Use to access the logs. Once that's all set, you'll see the Device Logs and hopefully able to symbolicate the logs to see what caused it crash. In the past, I've used this process to address crashes in our mobile web app (low memory, issues with webkit rendering, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This has happened because of "**low memory**", this is a memory issue.The **iPhone5's memory is larger than iPhone4's and iPhone4s's**. That's why this does not happen on the iPhone5 . This is a **performance issue**. Please improve your application's performance or solve the memory issue. Maybe in your application, some functions are using more memory and thats why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is indeed a **memory-problem**, the only way to remove crashes, is to improve the pages performance. I recommend to use the full build page and then start to **remove** parts out of it one by one, until you are at the point where the page works fine.

In this [blogpost](http://css-tricks.com/crashing-mobile-webkit/) the author describes, that removing one single comment can make the bug disappear.

This whole process is really painfull, but there is *yet* no other possibility for debugging this type of error.

Also Note: In development-mode, the Browser itself has less memory for rendering and page performance. So turning development off can make a big difference.